# Show that $\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{1}{x}dx = -\int_{-p_2}^{-p_1}\frac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

> Consider arbitrary $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb R^{+}$. Define $n_1 = -p_1$ and
>   $n_2 = -p_2$. Prove that
>
> $$\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{1}{x}dx = -\int_{n_2}^{n_1}\frac{1}{x}dx $$

We have

$$\begin{align}\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{1}{x}dx & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p_2 - p_1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p_1 + i\frac{p_1-p_2}{n}} \\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{n_2 - n_1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}-\frac{1}{n_1 + i\frac{n_2-n_1}{n}} \\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n_2 - n_1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n_1 + i\frac{n_2-n_1}{n}} = \int_{n_1}^{n_2} \frac{1}{x}dx = -\int_{n_2}^{n_1}\frac{1}{x}dx
\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

**Question 1**

Is it correct?

**Question 2**

Is there a better way?

Comment: First, it should be noted that if $0\in [p_1,p_2]$, then both integrals diverge. Otherwise, try making the substitution $u:=-x$.

Comment: @TheEmptyFunction I'm sorry, I failed to mention that $p_1,p_2$ are positive. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your answer is not completely rigorous, but can be readjusted to work. You need to take *any* partition of the interval, and then do similar calculations.

However there exists a quicker way – [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution):

- $f(x)=1/x$,
- $\phi(x) = -x$,
- $a=-p_1, b=-p_2$.

Then
$$ \int\limits_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac 1x\, dx = \int\limits_{-p_1}^{-p_2} \frac{1}{-x}\cdot(-1)\, dx = \int\limits_{-p_1}^{-p_2} \frac{1}{x}\, dx$$

Now we swap the limits on RHS, what incurs a change of sign.